# Laravel 4 collecting data from relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

In my application I have a Notifications table and a Users table, a notification can belong to many users, so in my notification class I have the following,

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

In my database I also have a a table called `notification_user` this sits alongside my `notifications` table. The `notification_user` table has the following rows,

notification_id, user_id, is_read, created_at, updated_at

I am running the following code to return the notifications for a specific user,

```
$notifications = Notification::whereHas('user', function($q){
        $q->where('user_id', '=', 101);
})->get();
```

The problem I finding is that this does not return the is_read attribute from the `notification_user` table which I desperatly need! I have tried adding,

`$notification->load('user')` after the query, but that just adds the users data as an object.

Is there away to get the relational tables data as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a little extra to your relations to tell laravel to pull extra data out of the pivot table. (Don't forget to do this on the other model in your relation as well)

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot('is_read');
}
```

You should then have a `->pivot` attribute available on your model with the `is_read` property. (e.g: $notification->pivot->is_read) This is covered briefly in the docs http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

If you already have the user ID, just to make things easier for yourself, can't you just use the relation between them?

```
$user = User::find(101);

foreach($user->notifications as $notifications)
{
    if ($notification->pivot->is_read === false)
    {
        // Notification is unread, lets do something
    }
}
```